# Es posible usar efectivamente CREATE ROLE y sus privilegios, GRANT y REVOKE dentro de una funcion en postgresql (version 9.4))

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo que construir dos funciones para usarlas en la creación de roles y en la asignación de un rol a un grupo según su categoría en postgresql.

**He aquí el código:** La primera función es para crear un usuario y llamar a mi segunda función que asignará ese usuario a un grupo según su categoría.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_addlogin(
IN _usuario character varying(30),
IN _contraseña character varying(4),
IN _categoria integer)
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
declare mensaje text;
BEGIN
IF(select count(rolname) FROM pg_roles where rolname = _usuario) = 0 THEN
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('CREATE USER %I', _usuario, 'LOGIN PASSWORD %I',    _contraseña);
    PERFORM sp_adduser(_usuario, _categoria);
    mensaje = 'Usuario de BD agregado con exito';
ELSE
    RAISE 'Ya existe un rol con el mismo nombre, especifique';
END IF;
return mensaje;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_adduser(
IN _usuario character varying(30),
IN _categoria integer)
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
declare
mensaje text;
BEGIN
IF(SELECT count(rolname) FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = _usuario) = 1 THEN
    IF(_categoria = 1 or _categoria = 2)THEN
        EXECUTE FORMAT ('GRANT', gestores, 'TO', _usuario);
        mensaje = 'Usuario añadido al grupo gestores';
    END IF;

    IF(_categoria = 3)THEN
        EXECUTE FORMAT ('GRANT', administradores, 'TO', _usuarrio);
        mensaje = 'Usuario añadido al grupo administradores';
    END IF;
 ELSE
    RAISE 'El usuario indicado no existe, reintente';
 END IF;
 return mensaje;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Al ejecutar la primera función genera este error:

```
ERROR:  column "gestores" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT FORMAT ('GRANT', gestores, 'TO', _usuario)
                            ^
QUERY:  SELECT FORMAT ('GRANT', gestores, 'TO', _usuario)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function sp_adduser(character varying,integer) line 7     at EXECUTE statement
SQL statement "SELECT sp_adduser(_usuario, _categoria)"
PL/pgSQL function sp_addlogin(character varying,character varying,integer)     line 6 at PERFORM

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "gestores" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Context: PL/pgSQL function sp_adduser(character varying,integer) line 7 at     EXECUTE statement
SQL statement "SELECT sp_adduser(_usuario, _categoria)"
PL/pgSQL function sp_addlogin(character varying,character varying,integer)    line 6 at PERFORM
```

Llevo un par de horas buscando como solucionarlo, pero francamente no sé qué estoy haciendo mal. Soy principiante en SQL y postgres, espero puedan ayudarme. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, se puede. El problema con tu código es que `gestores` es un identificador, el postgres entiende que es una variable o el nombre de una columna, pero no hay una variable definida (en la sección declare) con ese nombre, ni el EXECUTE está en un SELECT con un FROM cuya tabla (o cláusula FROM) tiene una columna llamada gestores.

Entonces si gestores es el nombre de la tabla habría que poner

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('GANT gestores ON'...
```

si no hay que declarar la variable